# Background is not displaying behind objects

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a little website for the hell of it and ran into a small bump, I'm just now learning Java and HTML and CSS so I haven't the slightest if its an easy fix, and couldn't find any info on it that seemed to be the same thing. What the problem is is that I made a background from a google image but the things I implemented beforehand didn't render on top of the said background. I will include my not-so-snazzy HTML code here, and any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body,
      html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .bg {
        background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
      function createText() {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("GFG");

        // creating text feild element
        var button = document.createElement("input");
        var button2 = document.createElement("input");




        // creating text to be
        //displayed on button

        // appending text to button

        // appending button to div
        myDiv.appendChild(button);;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body body style="text-align: center;">

    <h1 style="color:green;">
      Snake
    </h1>

    <h3>
      V1 JAVA test
    </h3>



    <p>Based on nothing </p>




    <button onclick="Geeks()">
      Login
    </button>



    <br><br>

    <div id="GFG"></div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I tried making the background render in a different way, that failed and just put text on the screen, I tried changing the position of things and that too failed.

Comment: What you are learning is called **JavaScript** not "Java".  Java is a completely different language.  Regardless, what's this supposed to do?  What is `Geeks()` supposed to do? (it's _missing_)  Who is supposed to call `createText()` (it's not called).

Comment: You are setting `background-image` in `.bg` div. 
Which is present after your headings, paragraph, etc. So that's correct. 
First you will have your text with while background and then `.bg` div with image.
If you want to include image in whole document try setting that css in `body{}` not `.bg{}`

Comment: Thank you @sachuverma for your help, very much appreciate it!!

Comment: @Wyck, geeks was a error on my part, it was the create text script, and you are very right about the javascript and java being different, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a really simple issue, you are trying to add a background image to to "bg" class, but what you really want is to have it set to your entire body. So the fix here is to simply replace .bg {....} with body {....}.

```css
      body {
        background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYWFRgVFhUYGBgYGBoYGBwZGhoYGBwaGhgcHBkZGhocIS4lHB4rIRgYJjgmKy8xNjU1GiU7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QHhISHjQrJCs0NDQ0NDY0NDQ0NjY0NDE0NDY0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NP/AABEIAMABBgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAECAwQGBwj/xAA9EAACAQMDAgQEBAUCAwkAAAABAhEAAyEEEjEFQSJRYXETMoGRBkKhsRQjUsHRcuEzYvAHFRZDk6Ky0vH/xAAZAQADAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX/xAAsEQADAAEEAQMDAwQDAAAAAAAAAQIRAxIhMQQiQVETYYEycbGR4fDxI0JS/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDtyKjU6gRSAamIqVMRQIjTGpRTRQAxpoqVKgCBpAVIilFAEYpEVKmIoAiBSipUqAKzUSKsIqMUARilFSimigBjSpRSoAUUqUUjQAqVKlFAD1p0rVlmtGlpMDeDT1BTT7qQxMKSsRwaW6kRQBemrI5rSurBocRTTQCDAug96VC0uxSoHkzEUxFSpVQiBWmIqZpUsiIRTbamRTRTAhFPFOaUUARIpoqVKgCMUxWsvVOq2dOu664WflHLN7KMmuS1f/aEsxbsk+rsF/8AaoP70AdvFKK86H4/vz/w7UeUPP33UQ0P4/QmLtop6o28fUEA0Bg7QimIrPoOo2ry7rTq4HMcj3HIrVFAEaaKlFQuOFEnFHQLngRFRJFDr2sZsLgfrVME8k1jWsl0dceJVLL4C24eYqRFBHT3prXUGQ5MilOsm+R34lJZTDe2lFRs3Q6hlNTrZM42sDBausc1Cp2+aMgaxT1FTUhTGIVIVGnqQJUxpTTUDGpU5FKkBVFKpUxFWIalSpUCGimqRpooAalTxSNAESKruuFUseFBY+wE1YxjJoJ1rUF7bqvBRh7+E1NUkXp6dW+Dy/V6t9Tda47HcxxJwo7KPICq36aeZofbcirzqTxJqhYZJ7O08xVLMBULl41ld6BpBroHVjYvpcBgSA47FCfED+9e0G4sTuEe4r58Q5r1kacqFUmSUQ98yoJ58qw1tb6a6Orx/FWvTWcHWMIEnA5ntQPW6sO0BsCtPQtQx3IwDKqzBKggcQAeaH9TQC8ypG1YHaOM5BzXLXk1S6OvR8OZ1HLfKNFi3IkSR5jipmtP4bLMr2z8ogrzgmaEapYuvtJgk54z347TWf1Dqic24+DRccRQnUNR3pXTlu2wzO07trCMCYgg/WhGutBWZVk7WKkkDsY7GrVyR3Tldofo+v2OEPyt+hrqa4NbLM4A85+1dOdQ57xXTOqkuTg1vGqq4CpqSGgx3f1H70luuv5qa15+CH4dfJ0iGpihGj6mCdr4Pn2oqrVtNKlwc1RUPDJikRSmmJpkCpTTTTGkA809QpUDJ1GpUiKoRA0+2lUqBFcUqelQAhUXcASadjGTQnUXi7QPlH61F0pRrpabusDai+XMDC/vUVsiCD5RV6W4oL+IPxJa03hgu8TsBAAHYs3b2g1zc0z00p04+x5brrWy46/0sR9jFZ5r0Xr34QbUgavSlSbiK722O3JUEm2xwfUGK4zU/h7VIYbTXh7W2YfdQRXWjzHhglzVRNbm6Zf72L3/AKb/AP1qI6Ve72nX/UCv/wAqTeBKWN0/Tl3RBkswUe5MD969q1+mS6P5bIbiiCBLbgMHJxXlfStOdPcS8+07GDBeZPb9f2rrOm9fUNvIdQGmFgBhztnmOK4td7msHo+MnK3ZwzpdJa/hwbj/ADMQoVVGO5gnvjmo3dA10/FSAr9nEsD9PahfUes2H2HKtuPczkZPOKODZ8AfCZWhDw8MCecA4PnXNjjB1bmsUnyy7pbog+FCi6u4nbKlj6N3PpQazpLjuE2tugnxDHuSM/WifStGyqbjB8qBmAwHO7zj170tOX1DjsgYHwtDKpnB8ySO5+lPbkSvY6qX+fuagf4axbSAXYlmyxHh5bAnmMVzfwXbdtli8s0CcEmSYwBNdD1V7bXVDruYgL4WAiTAWeMHn3qvqWpNhVW14dwBZhtY5nw7u4BHfypNIWjTnpZp/PRY9hbOnLC0BcCBTjdJnxMSOBEmaAnqENDqFjBiefUGtzPqHYAfELbcE+FdpMxEZBiJrdeUWdOpuW7bXFMLgNJ3R4iBxBOKFTQL0cPlt/JgVwRIII9KixrFc6ogH/DCCclT4YnACx9JrYrAiRwRIrWaVcltNdox6uiv4a6iXBtsZK5HtQXWvWXpmqNvUI3YnafY10Q8M4/IlVLPQ4pUppV1nmEaY1IimilgCMUqspUYGSimNPSpkkaVPFIigCFVX9Qqc8+VVanVx4Vye/pWMJmTk1jeqlwjp0tDdzXQ2r1LOIAgfqayJbYd6I/DxVZSuaqdPk74iZWJMjXmQSWgefevKOp3We47sSS7M0n3/wDyvVLmla6cMqqJmZkActx7VwX4j6T8G4ZMo/iDAEBXbJRp49P9jV6Frc0zLyozKaf7h/8ABvXl+Etpmh0kAeazKke0x9KP6nrRH5pHmcmvJXQg+RGQR/Y1b/H3gPn3e4z9xXU1k4Jwju9b1hjPjP8Amuc1vUO5NA7msunuv61la07HxN9uKzcN9mu9LofqGsLnaMgUtJddCRJgjI8vX0ptyr4VGfOlbMTPJ86dJKcF6SqqyEdNqSSFMkH7zXVdK0FxgNrDtyQrZ8xk1yHThLgY8pPAn9q7TQqQPmiMCG7dgp71w6uJPUhOnhHUaWyyKzX2ZmYCCM7Y/wBW32xip6fWXbiObbKFDKqLIDAfK84kcyCJ71Ho2oZ1YO0H5RhmuMCOd0wBigCjwFJETIHMwQZjtxWe7BM6bptPtYD2nvH4YVFY3OQCFYEBjInnBBgelKxpnbDuQp8aqpH5SMAkSonw1LRb7iqVI3ru2qw3MpyAWaYAyYH70Ji5bYE7lYGFb51JkkwxxEntU0wmW25WEzb1Lq17dDTZnIH5uT+aJImfSmt9bfHxFW4vcQFJIiCTEHjiKu0vWTIF4KyzG4KCwPnt4IHpx61PUHRXThtjSQSBsLDMEA+FmJio79ysTKU1H5QLvfw1zcxVkcqxUFgF3SCoHaPeq9ISqm27qXTB29hwAfXH7Vh61065aJU7XjkjO1JIQN/ST9qz9M3Lc2lQsp4iDO5pmZnmCMe1b6PYWpWHLyghqTQpm8af61/cUT1JoM7/AMxP9a/uK6V2c2p0z1ZDgewp6rtuIGe1Tmus8keo1KlSAjSpUqALqanqFxwokmBVdCw2OaG6vVlvCnHc/wCKjf1DPgSF/U0yWwK5r1c8I7tHx8eqv6ELSRVn0NWbhVT5rA61I3xKov6vbnHnnjFK5WbUaBngzgnxE8KAJgf1HvUU8I0hTnkxnWXGYEs0+mANxyMVTrNWruNLsDlwS5P5V9J/MefTFGFv2Vm3AIZRJRRAIGRu5A9R3mgum6cRqX1CjaoA2rMyYAIBPoJrFYT5Naapfpwjkeo9A1Fp2VEZ1XMAbiB6gZoQ18j5kU/cfsa9q1WpUqCsq22DP5if3oRrem2HXxoGmArcRElo+p+sV0T5TXD5OJ+PNctYPJX1P9KKPue3rUQpYHcT6DtXd9U6No7aM5meQJP2A/65riHbcSBj09O1bTrO+gXjSim3aJMAZq+5ZIHcR+nlWjToo/KfSD3jz981qRAVKsfUHvOP8VNXybzp7UV9EZFuIWMAsJPIAnhh3FdrbEsVQYLHYvzK/iiFPYwRXn9g7X7Ha3fg+/pXqia20o+OqHtsWAF2tA3rxmcSeKx1lk0mtvKC1lGsWSq7lcqWuGA68NAH9I7A1zVoKfCCsnlpIJHlnvW7S9eVSqjdbYkLc3HepHBcZBHfHEVl6nZa2xtSjLMqxUjmJg5+orOlwGgnNNV2+Q30IEW7hUkKsk5UMWVZCz/TE/cVjTr7FQbiI642rOAMyTM58sVYmnY2RZCqrkEkhwu7ggnb6Hgj/NcrqSQ20oogkc45zUhGnN1To6PrOiULbuW2XcwllQl9xOQUWO3eIA8sVy+p1c7jkGeTz7AUV0PVNoUXLnwdqna6oWZgcBeIj19KxXuorsd1X4kGN7qsxEnHY9/rRsLi6hbXzgj1XXsqWy9kFWQTLwbjKuGbaZgSDB86B6XVbXDqYMCQ3rEgeVVdTv72WCxO0CDGMdoNZDbYyPKAe2P75rohYRlSWDr/AOIDrIoS7fzF9DP2rHot6H5ZBMEfsYrQ58c1pPZhqcJnV6brDCJNdBoepBu9ef2HM9z+tdF0QGcyPet5o4Kg7JWmp1TY4FTLgcmtDDA+2lVFzXoO9KnkeDRrb62xLH2Hc0DvasO25jgcL2H+9QexVD2a5L1XXB6OnoTPPub01S9v0NTOq9foc0GKVAsRWZspDPxl74/anL+VBRqPP9KvS73BoLzg2XXPYScChtzWFt+4yY2qBO1c849J+5rRcLOCPSccnsAB71p/gkS3tZiqkhixHimYiO8Qayt/BpNSuwLbkMIEkEHmjqDbmQfIjz9D5c/pVVq+tlA6LkBlDMDL7mhSPOAp+goLqNS5EzOIUTGBwPSsnKS+5o6rVeUuEHWvECRyPl4kfWsvVNcm0HAgEEDEZLDPrumuX/8AEEYKuO3Ej9Mn7U17XpcHzA+xg/Y0KKS+wnM5yYNdcFwMAZkdxkQe1CbOnAaSIHc1vcoDJcA47xULvU0AZdxIJwAJ9OftW87ksJEvb2xxoCBIZT9YI8qw6rUbZUEHsSM+9ZdX1J2EKNo9Mk/Whu4+dbzpPujn1NbHCCtgL3OD5fvXYpqlXYhUFNgBAkAk8OO6twT6iuD0l8BhuFdfpTbYW3cqAqwRwWAJjA+aDHGdpqNWStO1RZdZ7TEOIZTG1gVkdjnzow/WU2K7BCDEAHxoRxJ+bsfSqLXV0uOFu2gwO34f5nUicSACViBHoPKgWoQyWZCJyJB4n2yaw2nT+prPZ0C68A73BhpZGB4k+UkA+YImgmo10uWcls5PmPPHBogttFTeRbZNglSx3T3JCmVPpXNvEk9s4maalBL5Zv6jrHbOCvYjPpBY/tQ1nZPKT2wY/wAVt07G2m/dlsBQYj1yCPtVF9FaXBj+oEjPtAq1wS69vYoR5UknIMjvPkKq8bmYPZfKae/qJACrkfX602msXGPhViSRgcz6CtOjLOWa9ILgcAbgY98CjlkI23cgBGWIPMkRj3Nafw8HsEF0JliSrSjRkHxGrdZZtPBs7UKzuRicgONvODhjwayV+rgVTxyvyE9MgjwgAelaNtDunXexIkeRmii1q/kzSQy3HX5WI+uKpuaxzgmr4rLq7eKqLaZGppTS+5Sz0q29M0C3UkvBBgiMimro3I4XFIIkVTcFaWNZ3FcR6qM7iqnStDVBhQBmZKzsCOMVrY1muGmUNb1pSWHzD5fKTiY9pqfUrstlt0BZ8txEsB9ZrGU3OqgxJAk8Ce9GbeiX4oI2sjKSCxJEhfED5t3+orK0XDmeX3yZtRp7nw0ZjKgeHMkBiSAfLv8AeqtLpGuAsq+FQCxxicSByfP6UX1etRF7FmEbRkKR3IPafrWXTa8XLh+KdoZCq7fCpYZVX9CJFRKy8sPqWo4Ri/EPT7EBVPxAEGwhgpUmSZgZ7Hzrg9VoXB+XA7xXb3XDOzAbZYkd1gnAphpVdtjCCxjERJ49qtU2+C5hTGaZ55/Ck9ifYTRXQfha9cX4gXavZmKhZ9ST4fqK9F6j0izaJF1CnhUL8ECG5ktPrQx0YqAq7UHcfm82bzOP8VValIznGpzK4+Tj7/Q4gK4JE7oU9vI9/eagn4Z3An4qTE/mBHqZH+a6/T6JrjhFG4sc7QOO5yY486LPYXTW2yA4MgEkOw4WdpjGeCKla1hrTC9C5Z5Jquh3UJgBwDys/sc0+m1b2m2XEOMQ4IYe0xXfXLz7medpYg44x25z9aIDQtqbQdzAkhvCCpA4Jkgeff6VovI3cNZM78f6eGng4+z1W3sQrlkMeKdwBjtPAjB7VuTUq7nYzPvEQ6gx57lbB9xmk/4e0rbgd87j4klQo7HaZGfaqB+FmHjsXn2jIY7SB5hpjNLOnXTG1c9oyahCjkbQ/kCCQceXNT09xmYhkmRhQox69orZd6FqFKu2pUEqSN67W29gQDms9roWruGQ4g+GVUSSeBEz9e1Hp/8ASHueMtGS9dRXhzuzk7jAHkAe496HavWgkqmRODMgD+5o9e/CCo227eZmn8qiIHPLZM0Z6R0fRJ4Lm5t5I3Fdu2D4YgnJ74PNG+J98sTVNbscHJ9L6Feu5tJMiZbwzH9Jbn2Fdh0n8Kai0ysGBYAsGD+HcAfAp7tgjyog/QCohWVjuKhY4/5i07VxmJ/xS/7oulSQUbYIIVyQARJKnj3FZVquuMFJT/1a/KCd/TJdRdzqditvdCCd5ztI7iSePIVxnUka2211hlgwwkZbhh7f3q3UeGCVKxBWQQWB4IptX1MtbIuM5YNvuY3KSo/lrIjaD3J8qmVljcuF3lMo6VfhyuOTke/l2rqk4rjrbAMpG35QAV7xEgjnHnXWaRpUHmuqejEu3VnvNNaGWszijoppAw32tsSvcQaVS1KZp6rcZuUdE1yqmeqnaqS9Zm2C0vUGeq2eqiaMAixzWd2p2es1x6Bozau53HIrX/H7lQJKhUAPYb4hmHqcTQvWNVPSdVLpZdgqFyZOIJAlR77RHrSqXS4HLSeWdJr74JSB/wCWob1aDJnzkx9K1dF0ZZg7KGQbiFOQxHhiPc8elXJds3VFsKdqkhbhkKoJ3Sx+hiqNN1C2ilGB3Kx2sDIIgxAJgZz9ayfA3TqNqX+jZq+nIw3ZRZUN4Zjkbo7ZWKWhupuexYC3FuCZfwtIHEkZ8xWPq9y4X2F9uAygEAEMJ5HOSTyYmh0iV8JDAghlJ+/vVThGf06qMt/sa9eIaDcLMAo8Un3XPEGRFQvkqQGBUHuslT9KL6zpQ8QVvisSfmIBPqPIgyD71j03TzbUX2uKhVgVRjMkMdy+hwcftU43M1nWmYX8BTp6k2N8W9ituYr4bm1R4sjg0F1ri5dJA+Gp43S0R9zmiWvG9fjsm226nFtuWmAHAECM5PNAkdfEN5WMgMCZ9DHFVqL2I8ZJt37/AMFuj6ebz7E2sYkkkAR50e1jfBtkhWdlVbZL7WRT5LxQzo+ldg5VFbbsM7thAkkhfU1DrV5WIW2jqgPjksZf2mJA71G3CyVqP6mqpb4QLRI4yc5NGvw5ZHiIYLkFmLAeHyUFT4uczQh7w27dxAAxIo50O9uRbXxbaj/iZEtM/KeB61nC9zXyX6MAzq5X4zMoO3Ay24sfPd3FVaEst1SpIZjt8M8NjsO3MelS6jq919mLhoYgECAQMCB5VRp9UBdVtxUhsMFnb6x3pY9RaX/Cl9joPxOo2YU7bRChuFBblTuMk8cCuZvDwLP/AFNGus3wbMMbxusysVcFQY5IWI44oAzGMbVjzOfp607XKI8X9GGdP1J91h1sgsqhGkDbbUKoLCJy3fvzXMDWMhlTuxlc7D5hoPFben6hfgshuuXdtoRCNrAgenJmKF9T0z23KlGRYwMFiO+VxzV7fcjS2zulhXqNxtSLZL7rhV9qKFAUCfmLHIhRk1zhRgrguF4ZpyHZSYAj1qzqTH4dpSgRIYl4G9zOZYZIAIEVlfVEWl+VkBZADz5yQDJPiOfatJkyeVOF0R0XO4xk9vLEf3rvumAbB7Vwtgjcqj5eRiIB7RXeaBYQYPFboyr2J3z9qynIrTqD9KyM1DGmZbwpVG81KgYQuPVRNUNqPOmFypNC4tVTvTM9Uu9ACd6y3Hp3eqGNSxlOoOKw9N0RvXgI8KZb37Crtfcgep4rqfwr0vZbBI8TeI1cmd9CWzcthltgbbgAYGOR3E+hP3oYhzDAk5H/ADA+Ufau0/hgRkULv6II3xFWWVgy84IPGcR/ipqE+UVpau1NNFeo0V29bt3EIaBsKzBXaDEk8AgT9aXRNL/MZfDkArvIAkEfKR8x7CDQ9daz3Crv8NWJyBgYJAPfbJj0FP1vWBiqSG2Kq7lBHA79sE81DGlTWz/P7nQ3NQqy7D+Yo/KYDSe+TBU+nnQbVah2Y3biK6Pg7cceZ7N61T0nXG3cliHVwVcHJ2n+/rUL+guKzqyOsZIALAA5BMdo70p6yhKFN4fZt6XbVmdC7orKcAEgkCYIPsM/rRO/0s3jKtuCBQQdswB8owCTA7nvWbpF1mTlS6GPERuZD+VR+bg80/U9aSj7FUKIViiysGRJx4TyJ9abeWRTpV6eDNq+ooG/kWHtAEBmRj4gOxXifrVepCXSpstcUO5Dq8sQezY5B/2oa2oVfDbuNtJEh8Z8yASMUd6a7JbYC4jK5G0gRuIbbncA0Y9uaKaaZe1xhrOfyDdLp7rMLMjlgNylR3JJPJGKIXNYFVdKx0+0A/zA0qDnLYmat12o2WmDqrO5baVJLGcKVK8xMdq5ZgigKbbBszPv2HbtUzwh86r54+Al1DTQwCFNuydysHUxywIExkc1DSWWuNLXFRUG9mKyAFPliciK09EuAW2C2wG3L4jhiGMBfbHepdXbZZ2vbXe/HEiCJO4cj696jHqNPqVjZ79FFzr6NcY3XZwPkZFAE5ElWzEGhx6aXG9UYqzeEuCsr2IEwaxvcYDbC/v+1EtRq0RLSu5ddpJCHaRncoyMZPlVPkNrj9JR1S7cS2mnJVEALysEsSxkzAIzOKyaDUFVuMFLgAeNpbYScgE4Bb+1LqSb51CKShO0bhwe4nif81nvo1u0PGAbkMQs4XMA9p+9UlknjH7i153hWV90TuUg+E8znkQO1YmtjYrgnaDnw7fF/jip6YEBnBjG35oAnuaoDbztB8IPPmfP2rRLBDXOAh0jSl33ZGZru9OjBee1C/w7o4E10nwxFV7GNPLBV3d6RWPUN6RRa9brFet4pZDAGZ6VT1FiDjFNV5DIXuaQGslzQ+RijG2oOlZ5NmgDcsOPWsd1yOcV0T26x3rIPIoABb5pM1bL+iA+XH7UK6g5RYjJ49aMBkn0vSm/fHdUMn37V6XptOAPpXOfhDpuxAxGWyfeup31T4MqeWIgCqLiSPKne761nu3+Zz+9JMeAX1LpwbsJrn9UhQRsAI7rifU+tdRcvKax37IYZown2Wqc8oB6O5ZUsbjEiJXaSDukYYfcH9KLaXqL6g7Q4ULB2s24soMkDHiCjMHzNCNb0zmKFXEdCCCcHHpSc46HvVd9hvrOsR7rFFCifyztxiR5Vd0zqJtOYYsjgq4JiQZ5IHaSeK5291H/AJIJ5g4/WtGj6vZtEuVDkrADCCpkGZ7HyIrPbWTTMbNp1DdE2sZuoUIBBAViZnGY2kfSaz6rWNZX4TIrQZVt0ss5ABUkD2oV0zra7y9zxqQQPFEHsfCM/UVivgqQTJVsiDgj3p0mTE84pnT6S7avLudijrLBVxOMbSTlscelYdH0p7qtcNxVVTHiaCf9OIke9CtEw3qxHgDDdJIXGSJHcitOu6qCxFuVQEkLO4ZOSGic+9JT8ltNPEs1dUYKotpcOxDnvuY9/wBfKsvTrybgt92KdguRu7SPL2io64pe/mW0CCAHEkwe7Z+nFYrCKc7lG0gx8rH/AEzyfekp5KytuH2GlOmDOGtktuGzxbFjtgDxGZ5mgvVN63HV02tPBgkA5A7wIpdR6g919ztjhdxWVHkIqi/q1dfEJfzEj7+f61e0zl7Xkv0eohHV/EkSFkr4uBx7dvKqk1e1WVyQjZIOSSOPX+1ZluvtC8Ace/nVWptkiSSfeqlLIqrOTDc1LOSoACTgD9JNH+gaAswxxFBul6Xc0Dzr0vonTdi8Zq6x0Z7sL7hHR2No4raeKiBUoqGTgz3qxXBit7D9qx3KB4B1+3NNWgilTJwEiardatBpmNSbszOlZriVsc1ncUBgwXLdYr9qeQDGc0TuVlurTyTgJaHrCqgBQ7hjBx71c/Ui3AigKrFXo9N8k4wE/wCIJ71C7dPnWdHqu89LoaHF/Oa0q8jFDeTWyzbMUIKLXUUJ1tkGid0YoRq3MxVJmeMgLV6fuKDatYrpr6yKGJojcuhBwMn2FVIN4Rg0WkMTHNE7WleIkx74rp9L0YCBFGNP0hfITSrkSvg4q1on4Ut6wTFWp0y5616Dpunp3gfrVraADj/ep2or6jPOG6Vc4k/rWdulMORXod/S+nesL6YHtRhFKmziF6W3lWm10k+VdiuhETFOdOB2pYB02cqvSjVOq0EKa6t0FC+pjwmnwLLMH4S6b+cjk4+9d1YSBQzomm2oojgCjKpQJ8iYUz1NgAMkCqnZcQw+9A0VO1ZLhq649Zi360iikT+lKnalTEf/2Q==");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```